# how to create Account in dynamics crm using asp.net?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

```
public List<AccountEntityModels> RetriveRecord()
{           
  using (OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService("MyConnectionString"))               
  {               
    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
    {                    
      EntityName = "account",
      ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name")
    };
    List<AccountEntityModels> info = new List<AccountEntityModels>();
    EntityCollection accountRecord = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    if (accountRecord != null && accountRecord.Entities.Count > 0)                    
    {                   
      AccountEntityModels accountModel;

      for (int i = 0; i < accountRecord.Entities.Count; i++)
      {                  
        accountModel = new AccountEntityModels();
        if (accountRecord[i].Contains("name") && accountRecord[i]["name"] != null)
          accountModel.AccountName = accountRecord[i]["name"].ToString();

        info.Add(accountModel);
      }
    }
    return info;
  }
}
```

Comment: Title asks for “how to create” but code is retrieving accounts from CRM.. are you reading from CRM A & creating to CRM B??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is for retrieving all the CRM accounts, storing in generic List collection and returning it.

If you want to create an account, use this code.

```
Entity account = new Entity("account");
account["name"] = "test account";
Guid _accountId = _service.Create(account);
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/sample-create-retrieve-update-delete-late-bound) for samples explained clearly, also about `_service` initialization.

Comment: Thanks you. If i want Update, i use this code:                                                                                                                                                                           
///  This code is correct                                                                                                                      
Entity account = new Entity("account");
account["name"] = "test account";
Guid _accountId = _service.Update(account);

Comment: @SanPhan this code is for create. For update code will be using service.Update() but you have to pass the key Guid.

Comment: using service.Update(Entity entity). i  don't know Guid in where service.Update(Entity entity).